# CSS to target final element within a dynamic content set

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to work out how I target the final element within a dynamically generated content set.

For example, all the generated content get spits out like so:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
      <div class="box">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <a href="#">A link</a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case I'd like the final paragraph to have a `margin-bottom: 0;`

But the content could also be generated like so:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
      <div class="box">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <a href="#">A link</a>
        <div class="inner-box">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where by I'd like the final paragraph within the `inner-box` div to be given the zero margin.

I've tried adding `block-inner:lastchild {margin-bottom:0;}` but that doesn't work correctly. Just wondering how the best way to target this. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any robust way to do this. `.box > p:last-child` will only get you a `p` element that is a child of `.box`; it won't match anything in your second example because the last child of `.box` is `.inner-box`, not a `p`.

`.box p:last-child` is not reliable because it will match all `p` elements that are the last children of their parents, which means it will match the last child of `.inner-box` here even though it's not the last `p` in the entire `.box`:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
      <div class="box">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <div class="inner-box">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        </div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
        <a href="#">A link</a>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And you have to worry about all the other possible ways the last `p` element could be nested somehow.

But if you know that the last `p` element can only ever either be a child of `.box`, or be a child of the last `.inner-box` for example, then you can enumerate those two possibilities:

```
.box > p:last-child,
.box > .inner-box:last-child > p:last-child
```

If you don't know the class name of that intermediate element you might be able to get away with not qualifying that `:last-child` at all:

```
.box > p:last-child,
.box > :last-child > p:last-child
```

And even then, that does not account for the fact that the last `p` may not even appear in the last child *of* `.box`.

Basically, you need to write a selector accounting for each and every possible nested structure in which the last `p` element may appear; there is no easy way to say "match the last `p` descendant of this container in a dynamic structure."

Comment: I think this is the best solution, as you said, I don't think it's possible to capture every scenario with one generic :last-child, so it will be a case of going in and adding different scenarios like you've listed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `p:last-child`

This will select the last `<p>` tag and only apply the styles to **it**.

```css
.box {
  border: solid 1px
}
.box p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-inner">
    <div class="box">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
      <a href="#">A link</a>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```